# Python 3-x Select a column and a row from a CSV table using SQL-like conditions

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, csv

Here's a CSV file `kidsList.csv`, comma-delimited, the first row is a header. The first column *Id* is unique so you can use this as a primary key.

```
Id,Name,Age
A1,Alice,6
A2,Becca,5
B1,Cindy,7
```

Now I want to find the name where Id is A2; the answer should be *"Becca"*.

In SQL it is like `SELECT Name FROM table WHERE Id = "A2"`

How can I do this in Python 3.x?  This operation is so simple that I want to use the Standard Library like `csv` rather than non-standard ones like `pandas`.

Comment: Hey, I've added an answer that will create an OrderedDict from csv.DictReader. Please check it out! If you know SQL, maybe check the "dataset" package to easily go from CSV --> SQLite. https://dataset.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: If Id is the key I suggest you index your data by Id and keep a reference of the row (values) from the index. You may do this indexing for each key column. The index may be stored in a map data structure. For non-indexed column search, it will be a full table scan (traverse all rows). Now, to support SQL like syntax you may need to write your interpreter if you wish to have similar syntax.

Comment: It is surprising that we can't really do such a basic SQL tasks using the CSV module alone %-/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the [csv.DictReader](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader) class can be utilized to create a dictionary mapping that you can index by the value of the Id column:

```
import csv
from collections import OrderedDict

kids = OrderedDict()
_name = 0
_age = 1

with open('kidsList.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, fieldnames=("Id",),restkey="data_list")
        for row in reader:
            kids[row["Id"]] = row["data_list"]

print(f"ID = A1 has data: name= {kids['A1'][_name]}, age= {kids['A1'][_age]} ")

# Expected Output:
# ID = A1 has data: name= Alice, age= 6
```

Comment: Yah, exactly to get the "Name" value. Glad this worked for you! You might try something like `_name= 0; _age= 1; print(kids['A2'][_name]);`

Comment: Cleaned up, thanks for catching that in public facing code!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the csv library to convert the csv file to a 2d list, and then loop through the array:

```
import csv

key = 'A2'
category = 'Name'

with open('kidsList.csv', 'r') as file:
    contents = list(csv.reader(file))

index = contents[0].index(category)

for i in range(1, len(contents)):
    if contents[i][0] == key:
        print(contents[i][index])
        break
```

Comment: No that's not what I meant.  I want to find the cell using a condition without knowing its row number.  In this example, "Becca" is in the second row but imagine that CSV file is longer and you want to do SELECT name FROM table WHERE Id = "C1".

Comment: Do you only index into the data by the Id value?

Comment: Yes.  Please note unlike key-value pairs (e.g. dictionary, JSON), it has 3+ columns.

Comment: @Culip sorry didn't quite understand your question, I've edited my answer to better address it

Comment: I got "IndexError: string index out of range".

Comment: @Culip typo, hopefully fixed